# $_POST select textarea by name?

Tags: php, post

I am still new to PHP so please forgive me for asking this:(

Let's say that I have input type text that looks like this:

```
<input type="text" id="wrapper_background_color"
value="'.$GetColorpickerValue.'" name="wrapper_background_color" />
```

So to do something with that input i can select it using $_POST like this (and that works fine)

```
$_POST['wrapper_background_color']
```

Now i will modify my text input **name** to this:

```
<input type="text" id="wrapper_background_color" value="'.$GetColorpickerValue.'"
name="theme_display_options[wrapper_background_color]" />
```

Now how can I select that **new name** using $_POST?

This will not work but illustrates my attempt:

```
$_POST theme_display_options['wrapper_background_color']
```

THX guys!!

Comment: HAve you tried `$_POST["theme_display_options[wrapper_background_color]"]` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You look for:

```
$_POST['theme_display_options']['wrapper_background_color']
```

in future use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to see what's the structure of your data:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$_POST['theme_display_options']['wrapper_background_color']
```

Answer (score 2):

just like we use multidimensional array :-

```
$_POST['theme_display_options']['wrapper_background_color']
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code in begining of PHP:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

you can find your answer...

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$wbc = "theme_display_options[wrapper_background_color]";
$_POST['$wbc']
```

or a multi one

```
$_POST['theme_display_options']['wrapper_background_color']
```

then the code of yours

Comment: You need to go back to the basics and re-read how it actually works. What you posted there is nonsense.